# How to check for the correct answer in wheel of fortune?

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf

I have this wheel of fortune [application](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8daj2h0oryis257/Capture.PNG?dl=0). The wheel is a whole image.
I am able to spin and detect the angle when the wheel stops spinning.
This is the code for that:

```
private void SpinBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var ease = new PowerEase { EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut };

            Random rng = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
            //DoubleAnimation(FromValue. ToValue, Duration)
            double degree = rng.Next(360, 720);
            DoubleAnimation myanimation = new DoubleAnimation
                    (0, degree, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));

            double resultAngle = degree - 360;
            double num = resultAngle % 45;
            double quadrant = num + 1;


            data.Content = resultAngle;

            //Adding Power ease to the animation
            myanimation.EasingFunction = ease;

            RotateTransform rotate = new RotateTransform();

            img.RenderTransform = rotate;
            img.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
            rotate.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, myanimation);


        }
```

However how do I check if the user drags the word to the textbox tallies with the image the pointer is pointing at? My lecturer requires me to store the words (I get from database) into an array and the object number in an array but I have no idea how to do it.
For example, object number 1 will fall in the angle range 0-45, object number 2 in 46-90 and so on. How do I go about with the checking?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure whether I have completely understood what the problem here is!
But you can simply use a `Dictionary` to hold string values of each 45-degree slice and check it against the word user drags.

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
dict.Add(1, "Eraser");
dict.Add(2, "Glue");
dict.Add(3, "Pen");
dict.Add(4, "Scissors");
dict.Add(5, "Stapler");
dict.Add(6, "Sharpener");
dict.Add(7, "Ruler");
dict.Add(8, "Pencil");
```

And change your code to:

```
double degree = rng.Next(360, 720);
double resultAngle = degree - 360;
int num = (int)Math.Ceiling(resultAngle / 45);
```

Then, the name of the element the pointer is currently pointing at would be:

```
string currentElem = dict[num];
```